# Pass different context to ngIf

Tags: angular

Take the following template example. The Im creating a template context of user with the `as` syntax and would like to pass that context into the `userTmpl`. From what I can tell there's no way to pass context outside of what is used by the ngIf condition. Which in this example, is the showUser property.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="user$ | async as user">
    <ng-container *ngIf="showUser; then userTmpl; else emptyTmpl"></ngcontainer>
</ng-container>
```

How can you pass the `user` template input variable to the nested templateRef?

*[Looking at the source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_if.ts#L116), the `ngIf` directive looks like it sets the context to the condition of the `ngIf`. Im not aware of a way to basically override that context variable thats used within the templates*

Something like this would be ideal, but not seeing a way to do it.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="showUser; then userTmpl; else emptyTmpl; context: user"></ngcontainer>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the reasons for the voting to close. If you are confused by the question, could you please provide reasons so I could clarify?

Comment: Probably not what if/else is designed for. Closes u can get is probably nesting ur templates in the ngIf: https://plnkr.co/edit/SIu6HBOOB8ofe3exA7lG?p=preview But that's still something I wouldn't encourage. Why don't u make use of a component ?

Comment: so basically you want to create a variable `user` in the outer `ngIf` and use it in the inner `ngIf` condition?

Comment: Not for the inner condition, the context for the templates `userTmpl` and `emptyTmpl`

Comment: @Maximus thanks for your posts too! :)

Comment: @cgatian, you're welcome) by `context` you mean to use something like this `{{user}}` inside the `userTmpl`?

Comment: @Maximus exactly! Checkout the ng source I reference in the post, the $implicit looks like its set to the conditional value. FrederikPrijck solution works, but its unfortunate you need to nest your templates within the ngIf.

Comment: `ngIf` uses the same context object for `else/then` templates - `this._thenViewRef =
              this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._thenTemplateRef, this._context);` - `user` should be available there

Comment: @Maximus checkout [this plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/Vx1jxkrezMYJGEwuzuOM?p=preview) In `app.ts` the thenTmpl is trying to use the user variable as context in the template.

Comment: yeah, the problem seems to be that templates `userTmpl` are `emptyTmpl`   are compiled in the context of host component, and that is why `context` passed by `ngIf` is ignored. The template on which the `ngIf` directive is placed is compiled in the context of `ngIf` only

Comment: Thats what Im seeing as well. Do you agree there's some benefit in proposing a feature to allow context to be passed via microsyntax as I've outlined in the answer?

Comment: yeah, that would be beneficial

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There are two very similar ways to solve this. I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-passing-different-context-to-ngif) with the two solutions (tested with Angular 6.0.1 and the latest 6.1.8) for passing data to different templates based on a condition.

version #1

```
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="showUser ? userTmpl : emptyTmpl; context: { $implicit: user }">
    </ng-container>

    <ng-template #userTmpl let-user>
        ...
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #emptyTmpl let-user>
        ...
    </ng-template>
```

version #2

Another possibility is to use @Ben's solution, but then you have to omit the `let-user` part (and fix the closing tag in his code). This way the code would look like this.

```
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="showUser ? userTmpl : emptyTmpl; context: user">
    </ng-container>

    <ng-template #userTmpl>
        ...
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #emptyTmpl>
        ...
    </ng-template>
```

Comment: Your answer would work but is slightly different since it doesn't use `*ngIf`

Comment: @cgatian yes, you're right. I started of trying to find a solution with `*ngIf` but somehow got carried away... sorry for that! I've modified my stackblitz to set the context _based_ on an `*ngIf` expression. That way it's at least possible to pass different data. Unfortunately it's still doesn't work like your ideal example.

Comment: Nevermind, I just saw that @Edmundo Rodrigues suggested the same.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [NgTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet).

Something like that would work:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="user$ | async as user">
    <ng-container *ngIf="showUser">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="userTmpl; context: { $implicit: user }"></ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #userTmpl let-user>
  {{ user | json }
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I don't think that there's a solution for this since it's not possible to use two structural directives in the same element at the same time.

Comment: Its not a structural thing though.  `ngIf` could use microsyntax to provide context, I just dont see it in the source.

Comment: I see. Well, looking at the source code, definitely there's no way for doing it currently - and I don't think that there will be one in the future.

Comment: You can use a component instead, or create a custom structural directive that does this job for you.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes you can!**

Your `$implicit` is the `x` and `x` is `user` from ngif (in your case)

Because `this._context.$implicit = this._context.ngIf = condition`

Check this example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <div *ngIf="user;then content else other_content">here is ignored</div>

    <ng-template #content let-x="$implicit">{{x|json}}content here...</ng-template>
    <ng-template #other_content>other content here...</ng-template>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  user = { name: 'wizardnet972' };
}
```

Comment: In my case the ngIf is `showUser` which is not the content I want to display within the template. `user` is what I want to pass to the template, and `showUser` is used within the ngIf

Comment: See my ideal example at the end of the question. Context is different than the ngIf conditional.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that this way :

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="showUser ? userTmpl : emptyTmpl; context: user"></ngcontainer>
```